# Text align in specific position

Tags: horizontal-alignment

[image]

I want to write a sentence like a picture above.
But I don't want to use `\hspace` (I have to make space every time), itemize(numbering space looks ugly to me) and indent(I have to change line everytime).
Is there any smart and easy way to make that result?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far?

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried?

Comment: @Zarko ^^ Chorus ....

Comment: @Zarko I tried hspace, itemize and indent space, but all of them takes too much time(I add them every sentence). I wish I can use only one code for this correction.

Comment: And you expect that we will write your code from scratch? Provide at least not working example with your text. Sorry, such unusual demand about formatting of list require additional effort.

Comment: See, if the `linegoal` package can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An unorthodox macro to avoid even use curly bracket. The syntax  is `\mymacro whatever: whatever |` and nothing else. Because will be not inside an environment with a defined end, is up to you reset the counter if you want to make another list below.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage{linegoal} 
\newcounter{mycount}
\def\myitem#1:#2|{\par\noindent\addtocounter{mycount}{1}
(\arabic{mycount})\quad #1: \parbox[t]{\linegoal}{#2}\smallskip}
\begin{document}
\myitem Terms of trade effect: \lipsum[1][1-3] |% note the ending "|" 
\myitem Firm delocation effect: \lipsum[1][1-2] | 
\myitem Profit shifting effect: \lipsum[1][1-2] |
\end{document}
```

But maybe is more elegant having a fixed hang indentation. The problem with a tabular is that cannot overlap the description of the item with the item title, like in `description` environment, that could be very convenient when titles are long or there are little space for descriptions.  In this case, the `\myitem`  could be even simpler, removing the odd end symbol:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\newcounter{mycount}
\def\myitem#1:#2{\par\noindent
\addtocounter{mycount}{1}
\hangindent10em(\arabic{mycount})\quad\textbf{#1}:\quad #2 }
\begin{document}
\myitem Terms of trade effect: \lipsum[1][1-3]
\myitem Firm delocation effect: \lipsum[2][1-2] 
\myitem Profit shifting effect: \lipsum[3][1-2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're not considering a table-based setup with automatic line-breaking in the third column.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' environment and 'X' column type
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % no full justification
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begingroup % limit the scope of the next instruction to the current group
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l l L @{}}
(1) & terms of trade effect & \lipsum[1][1-2] \\
(2) & firm delocation effect & \lipsum[2][1-2] \\
(3) & profit shifting effect & \lipsum[3][1-2]
\end{tabularx}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```